# How to express 10/3 = 3 . by using notations like mod?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you express 10/3 = 3 . by using notations like mod?

I need to express that k/3=something with out remainder such that

10/3=3
2/3=0
5/3=1

Answer (score 3):

You want the floor function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

The floor function takes a number and rounds it down to the next whole number. So, for example, 10/3 = 3.333... but floor(10/3) = floor(3.333...) = 3.

Comment: thanks , just what i need!